# Mongoose connection to mongodb database error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my node.js project to mongodb database using mongoose but its showing an error message instead of a connection success message. I'm following a youtube tutorial and I've done exactly what they did but its not working from my end. Please I need a solution.

I tried using "dotenv" with the mongoose connection but its still giving the same error.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/) for common problems. Most likely you need to whitelist your IP. Also, please don't post pictures, just copy and paste the error into your post. Lastly, don't put any sensitive data on SO such as usernames, passwords and cluster addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's noted.